# isin pandas retrieve null values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find dataframe values exist in another dataframe, I used isin function but it retrieve only values for the first column. ex: df1 has 5 columns, and df2 has 10 columns. The output I need all rows from df2 depend on column B1 value  in df2.
Example

df1

| A1 | A2 | A3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DC | loss | battery |
| Power | door | DC |
| battery | link | AC |

df2

| B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 | B5 | B6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DC | Two | Three | One | Two | Three |
| battery | GG | 44 | kk | ii | pp |
| AC | Two | Three | One | Two | Three |
| circuit | Two | Three | One | Two | Three |
| door | SS | TT | BB | RR | EE |
| current | Two | Three | One | Two | Three |

The needed output

df3

| B1 | B2 | B3 | B4 | B5 | B6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DC | Two | Three | One | Two | Three |
| battery | GG | 44 | kk | ii | pp |
| AC | Two | Three | One | Two | Three |
| door | SS | TT | BB | RR | EE |

I used the code :

```
df3_1 = df2[df2.B1.isin(df1.A1)]  
  
df3_2 = df2[df2.B1.isin(df1.A2)]

df3_3 = df2[df2.B1.isin(df1.A3)]
```

only df3_1 has correct values ,df3_2 and df3_3 are empty. I don't know the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason should be traling spaces, try remove them, also convert values to lowercase:

```
s = df2.B1.str.strip().str.lower()
df3_2 = df2[s.isin(df1.A2.str.strip().str.lower())]
df3_3 = df2[s.isin(df1.A3.str.strip().str.lower())]
```

Comment: It is worked for me, but I don't understand why this is the reason and why to convert values to lowercase . Please provide me with more details.

Comment: @asmaamahmoud - Because `isin` not match `battery` with `Battery` - so lowercase create same values - here  `battery` with `battery` and matching working well

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use a single [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) :

```
df3 = df2.loc[df2["B1"].isin(np.unique(df1))]

# using `df1.map(str.strip)` instead of `df1` could be needed in your case
# and same goes for `df2["B"]`, you may need to use df2["B"].str.strip()
```

Output :

```
print(df3)

        B1   B2     B3   B4   B5     B6
0       DC  Two  Three  One  Two  Three
1  battery   GG     44   kk   ii     pp
2       AC  Two  Three  One  Two  Three
4     door   SS     TT   BB   RR     EE
```

Comment: `df1.to_numpy().ravel()` could also be `np.unique(df1)` ;)

Comment: I still don't have this reflex yet. Thanks mozway, let me update ;)